# DataFrame - Given a start date, end date , hours incurred daily, how do I go about calculating hours incurred for given month/year?

Tags: python, dataframe

i have a dataframe consisting of employee_id, start_date, end_date, hour_spent_per_day. basically for each record, it captures the hours spent per day for the employee and for the duration given bhy start_Date and end_Date.

| employee_id | start_Date | end_Date | hours_spent_per_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2019-01-15 | 2019-01-15 | 2 |
| 1234 | 2019-01-15 | 2019-01-17 | 3 |
| 1236 | 2019-01-29 | 2019-02-28 | 4 |
| 1237 | 2019-01-19 | 2019-03-05 | 2 |
| 1237 | 2019-12-01 | 2020-01-10 | 2 |

My objective is to have a summary of total hours spent per month per year.
i.e.

| Year | Month | Hours Spent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | January | 'hours spent for all the days in Jan-2019 for all employees |
| 2019 | February | 'hours spent for all the days in Feb-2019 for all employees |
| 2019 | March | 'hours spent for all the days in Mar-2019 for all employees |
| 2019 | December | 'hours spent for all the days in Dec-2019 for all employees |
| 2020 | January | 'hours spent for all the days in Jan-2020 for all employees |

Now the second table would be easy (just a matter of group by SQL) . However I am having problem with the first table , i.e. for each row, how do I determine the hours spent for each month (noting cross-month is possible). I guess I need to determine the exact month/year covered for each row and then multiply the hours spent for the month. i am stuck , seeking your kind assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df["start_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start_Date"])
df["end_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["end_Date"])

df["tmp"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: pd.date_range(x["start_Date"], x["end_Date"]), axis=1
)
df = df.explode("tmp")

x = df.groupby([df.tmp.dt.year, df.tmp.dt.month_name()])[
    "hours_spent_per_day"
].sum()

x.index = x.index.rename(["Year", "Month"])
print(x.reset_index().rename(columns={"hours_spent_per_day": "Hours Spent"}))
```

Prints:

```
   Year     Month  Hours Spent
0  2019  December           62
1  2019  February          168
2  2019   January           49
3  2019     March           10
4  2020   January           20
```